# Download data from URL link in Android by using an HTTP Request

Tags: android

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {

    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

I just want to download data from URL link and display it using single button click in android, please help me on this.
[Here is the link](http://syndication.indianexpress.com/rss/latest-news.xml)

Comment: Do not ask for code directly. show some effort and show what you tried.

Comment: For the starter, please learn how to [perform network operations](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html).

Comment: at least give me some guideline or give me some stpes to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

// Your call

```
   String result = GET ("http://syndication.indianexpress.com/rss/latest-news.xml");
```

// FUNCTION

```
 public  String GET(String url){
    String responseXML = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;

    try {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = getHttpClientImpl();

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            if (is != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8 * 1024);
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);// .append("\n");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    is.close();
                }
                responseXML = sb.toString();
            }
            entity.consumeContent();
        }
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return responseXML;
 }
```

Comment: I will try to implement this

Comment: and one more thing to ask you

Comment: about which layout should i use for XML

Comment: It depend but in your case go for relative or linear layouts.

Comment: I got the result in Log.d(test,result) and I want that result in textview after clicking that button. for that create multi line text view. Can u please help to put that result in textView

Comment: I think you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10399301/3819810

Comment: I found the solution ed.setText(result)..

Comment: sir Now I want that data display using XML parsing in listview with single click button so Please Help me.

Comment: /************** Read XML *************/
                     
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new StringReader(XMLData));
InputSource is=new InputSource(br);
                     
/************  Parse XML **************/
      XMLParser parser=new XMLParser();
        SAXParserFactory factory=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
           SAXParser sp=factory.newSAXParser();
              XMLReader reader=sp.getXMLReader();
                 reader.setContentHandler(parser);
                   reader.parse(is);

Comment: have you parse it correctly? then follow this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: how to get editText result into one string in other method

Comment: and How to use XML parsing...